# Invalid type when generate the json?

Tags: c#

I've this json:

```
{
    "page": "36",
    "bookmaker_urls": {
        "13": [{
            "link": "http://www.bet365.com/home/?affiliate=365_179024",
            "name": "Bet 365"
        }]
    },
    "block_service_id": "competition_summary_block_competitionmatchessummary",
    "round_id": "36003",
    "outgroup": "",
    "view": "1",
    "competition_id": "13"
}
```

I've inserted this on this tool: http://json2csharp.com/

this will return:

```
 public class __invalid_type__13
    {
        public string link { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class BookmakerUrls
    {
        public List<__invalid_type__13> __invalid_name__13 { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int page { get; set; }
        public BookmakerUrls bookmaker_urls { get; set; }
        public string block_service_id { get; set; }
        public int round_id { get; set; }
        public bool outgroup { get; set; }
        public int view { get; set; }
        public int competition_id { get; set; }
    }
```

why there is an invalid type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`13` is not a valid property name in .NET, and the tool you're using seems to try to map each JSON property to .NET Class property.

What you probably want is `bookmaker_urls` to be a dictionary:

```
public class BookmakerUrl
{
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int page { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, List<BookmakerUrl>> bookmaker_urls { get; set; }
    public string block_service_id { get; set; }
    public int round_id { get; set; }
    public bool outgroup { get; set; }
    public int view { get; set; }
    public int competition_id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The generator generates the name of properties and types from the name of properties in the Json.

There is a property "13" in the Json. A name starting with a digit would not be a valid name in c#.

So, the generator just adds the prefix "**invalid_name**" or "**invalid_type**" to the generated names. This does not mean that there was any problem or that you cannot use the generated code.